# Is there any animation to demonstrate if the sea level rise up?

Tags: climate-change, sea-level

I found a very cool video here:

Draining Earth's oceans, revealing the two-thirds of Earth's surface we don't get to see

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uOwv_Krqk8&feature=emb_logo

However, I am looking for a video that demonstrates the sea-level goes up. I think there'd be many of them because it's a result of the Global warming. But I can't find any. Can someone post one?

Comment: Suggested search terms: sea level rise coastline.

Comment: Not an animation per se, but there are some simulators. The one at NOAA (https://coast.noaa.gov/slr/) is limited to the US and a 10 feet (~3 m) rise. Flood Map (https://www.floodmap.net/) covers the world and you can simulate any water level. You could use it to generate many maps with a gradual increase, and put the resulting images together to build an animation.

Answer (score 1):

There is this NASA animation showing 12-13 years between 2002 and 2015. It is interesting for showing the counter-intuitive lowering of sea levels nearest to land based ice mass losses, especially around Greenland and Pacific Alaska. This is due to local gravitational effects, ie less ice mass reduces the pull on ocean water near where the ice melts, so water levels actually fall in such places, whilst places furthest from them experience the greatest sea level rise.

(Any tips for embedding this video?)

https://youtu.be/VY_SeZiBcM4

Comment: i do not think it is possible to post videos on SE but you can post gifs,not sure how it is done but it has been done from time to time in chat rooms maybe ask how it is done in meta.

Comment: Imo, it's so pleasing to the eye and brain to not have to look screen-dominating splash screens of youtube-explainers and things. Better have a link, best with a few accompanying words of what it's about. Some people principally don't klick youtube-links ... :-)